# Select subquery for duplicate

Tags: sql

```
last_name   first_name  id_no   Race
Carlos      Pat         45      07-White
Anderson    EJ          8       03-Black or African American
Inplace     Mom         9       08-Other Race
Inplace     Teen        10      08-Other Race
Ball        Sumu        18      07-White
Ball        Sumu        18      07-White
```

i would only be interested Ball Sumu as it is a duplicate. there are 12000 rows

i have this code but is faulty.

```
select ac.last_name, ac.first_name, ac.id_no, ri.description as race from all_clients_view ac
inner join race ra
on ac.people_id = ra.people_id
inner join race_info ri
on ra.race_info_id = ri.race_info_id
where ac.people_id in (select ce.people_id from race ce)
order by id_no
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to see which entries are duplicated, try something like:

```
select last_name,first_name,count(*) from all_clients_view group by last_name,first_name having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: they aren't duplicated in the client table, but in the race table. i can run your query on the race table though.

Comment: select ra.people_id, ra.race_info_id, ac.last_name, ac.first_name, ac.id_no, count(*) from race ra
join all_clients_view ac
on ra.people_id = ac.people_id
group by ra.people_id, ra.race_info_id, ac.last_name, ac.first_name, ac.id_no having count(*) > 1
this gives only the exact matches. I have some cases where the race is entered twice for a client. Not exact match. I have to locate those as well. For bi-racial we have a value for bi-racial but some enter 2 anyway. I need to locate the race where it's not exactly the same.

Comment: I don't know, I am answering the question from the info you have provided. My answer was voted up as useful, now it isn't, and you are adding to the question. Tell you what, if the idea of a having clause was useful to you, vote my response up. The rest is up to you.

Comment: yes your answer is very helpful. I did not know they were entered duplicated race info. But I also need to know where they enter different race info. It's supposed to be one race record per client. They have 'biracial' but not being used. We are like an open user community people run excels with the data and this will throw off numbers.

Comment: is there a way your query can be inclusive to those that have the same last name, first name and id. But when joining to the race table there are 2 races or more for that set.